# VMware Virtual to Physical conversion?

Tags: v2p

Is there a program which will allow me to convert a VMware guest host VM into a physical image?

I know how to go P2V, but I need to go V2P.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Doing to a V2P of Linux should be very easy.  Just boot a livecd on the new system build your filesystems and use rsync or tar, or your favorite tool and transfer the files from the virtual machine.

Windows may get tricker depending on your hardware.  But I have booted used Ghost, and Acronis within a VM to capture an image of the VM and then restored it on physical machine.  Any disk image tool should work.  The important bit is making sure you physical hard disk controller will be supported before taking the image.  This may mean you need to install the controller driver in the VM before you capture.

Comment: This is quality advice, thanks for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: This doesn't cater for partitions, LVM, SElinux (and more...)

Answer (score 2):

As of right now there isn't a VMWare tool to do this, but you can look [here](http://www.vmware.com/support/v2p/) for info on it.

EDIT: More reading [here](http://www.vmware.com/support/v2p/doc/V2P_TechNote.pdf). Also, my favorite tool for full imaging across disparate hardware, and P2V and V2P scenarios is [ShadowProtect Server](http://www.storagecraft.com/), you can get a fully featured 30 day trial which will be more than enough to do a quick move.

All this is assuming you are running Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Another tool which does V2P, V2V, P2P, P2V is [platespin migrate](http://www.novell.com/products/migrate/).

Like the earlier post there should be a 30 days trial which would be enough to do your migration.