# Virtual to Physical desktop cloning

Tags: windows-xp, disk-image, bsod

I am trying to clone a VMware Workstation VM so I can load it on the computers around our office.

The VM in question is a Windows XP SP3 VM with a 40GB IDE VMDK.

I am seriously missing something and I am close to giving up on this. The problem happens when I clone the VM, I software of choice is Clonezilla (current version as of 05-19-2011).

The steps I followed were;

I prepare the machine as I want it,
Run sysprep and reseal the machine to preapre for resure,
Then I start the VM up and boot from the CD (ISO) instead of allowing it to boot into Windows.

For some reason which must be beyond my understanding, when I finish loading (restoring) the image onto the physical computer. The machine boots and then keeps rebooting, the odd thing is it appears to be a STOP error but it crashes the absolute second after the BIOS is done. The part right after it looks for a CD to boot from. No blue screen just the sound of POST starting again.

What the heck is going on? The only thing I can think of is something to do with the HAL. The is obviously more to this, any ideas?

Any help would be very appreciated.

I have already seen the post on ServerFault as listed here:
[Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/169008/vmware-virtual-to-physical-conversion)

**Sidenote**

My boss won't let me upgrade my NAS until I fix this computer :(

He is holding 4TB WD Black drives hostage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had problems doing this the other way (physical to virtual) and it is usually either differences in disk controller architecture between the P & V environments or the HAL. I came across this page on VirtualBox's web site which discusses replacing HAL.DLL in the recovery console. It worked for me, I suspect it could also work in a virtual to physical scenario.

http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Migrate_Windows